# Multithreaded Singleton WCF Service

Tags: wcf

In his book "Programming WCF Services", Juval Lowry expresses concerns about using Singleton Services because of the performance implications.

In one of my projects I'm using a stateless singleton WCF Service declared like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
   ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class FooService : IFoo
{
}
```

The service is accessed from multiple Silverlight clients over httpsTransport. I've opted for a singleton because I see no need to burden the system the GC overhead when it is not really needed. Am I missing something or shouldn't this be the most efficient way to implement a stateless service that's equally fast if not faster than a PerCall instantiated service?

Comment: What type of stuff is going on in this service, that you would be concerned about gc overhead.

Comment: @Nix: InstanceContextMode.Single avoids a new instance of the service itself to be instantiated for every call.

Comment: that didn't answer my question..

Comment: @Nix I think I did. My remark about GC overhead was aimed at the fact that the service alone will be constantly GC'd. Regardless of its inner workings.

Comment: So you are purely concerned with the gc of the service and now any underlying code.  How often are you going to be calling this thing?

Comment: Ok I've upvoted all 3 answers because everyone contributed some useful information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not missing anything. If your service class has no instance member variables, which would represent state that could obviously be corrupted by multi-threaded access, there is nothing to fear.

I personally always use Single+Mulitple mode because all of my state is always coming from a cache or SQL database or some other shared resource where you need patterns to guard against concurrency anyway. I've never found a need for member variables in my services. Statics? Sure maybe, but then you know to protect them anyway.

Now this is all my personal opinion on PerCall vs. Single. *PerSession* services on the other hand could/most likely would have state maintained in the instance, but I personally don't find myself writing many of those and on the rare occasion I have, they are ConcurrencyMode.Single anyway.

[Check out this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681240%28VS.100%29.aspx) for more discussion and actual performance comparison of the diff. Modes.

Comment: That's exactly the style I prefer as well. None of my services have any instance members.

Answer (score 7):

Your assumption probably holds true for a WCF service configured for basicHttpBinding with no SSL (see [here for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733080.aspx)) but that is not likely true for other bindings. Although your application code may truly be stateless and/or thread safe, WCF uses [sessions internally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx) to support functionally in other bindings. This implies only one session per request can be handled since there is only a single service instance.

Seems like picking the singleton pattern is a case of premature optimization. Optimizing for GC efficiency should only be a concern when you have a proven need.

Comment: I'd hardly call avoiding unnecessary object instantiation and therefore unnecessary GC pressure using a one liner premature optimization :) YMMV

Comment: @Oliver, I'd call going against the recommendations (which I believe are to use percall model for stateless services for best throughput) to avoid something which you don't know is going to be an issue premature  :)

Comment: "Per-call services must be state-aware; that is, they must proactively manage their state, giving the client the illusion of a continuous session. A state-aware service isn’t the same as a stateless service. In fact, if the per-call service were truly stateless, there would be no need for per-call activation in the first place. It is precisely because it has state, and an expensive state at that, that you need the per-call mode." Programming WCF Services, 4th Edition by Michael Montgomery, Juval Lowy.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons that you'd want to avoid singletons is because generally you'd have a shared resource that you MUST make thread safe.  Once you do that, you have the possibility of stacking up service calls in a serial queue since only one call will be allowed in that critical section at once.

Since you have a stateless singleton, that probably won't be an issue.  It would, however, make it easy for that sort of thing to occur later on.

Comment: I am totally aware of the mess it would become as soon as you make it stateful but this question is explicitely about stateless singleton services.

Comment: @Oliver: I was stating why I think it was discouraged.  We had IDesign give us a master class on WCF several years ago and I distinctly remember that.  I agree with you that it shouldn't be an issue as long as it is stateless.  Under a stressful situation, it is likely more performant.  The degree in which it is more performant may not be worth the chance that the above scenario gets introduced at a later date.